# Edit Function doesn't pick the respective values

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, mysqli

i'm creating a ticketing  system and i need some assistance. The code directly below displays the database records and the delete works fine. The edit however isn't working.

```
 <?Php
        require "config.php";           

        $page_name="currentout.php";  
        $start=$_GET['start'];
        if(strlen($start) > 0 and !is_numeric($start)){
        echo "Data Error";
        exit;
        }


        $eu = ($start - 0); 
        $limit = 10;                                 
        $this1 = $eu + $limit; 
        $back = $eu - $limit; 
        $next = $eu + $limit; 

        $nume = $dbo->query("select count(id) from receipt")->fetchColumn();


        echo "<TABLE class='t1'>";
        echo  "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Pass</th><th>Amount</th><th>Action</th></tr>";


        $query=" SELECT * FROM receipt  limit $eu, $limit ";


        foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row) {

        @$m=$i%2;
        @$i=$i+1;   
        echo "<tr class='r$m'><td>$row[id]</td><td>$row[name]</td><td>$row[phone_num]</td><td>$row[Amount]</td><td><a href='delete.php?id=$row[id]'>delete</a></td><td><a href='edit.php?id=$row[id]'>Edit</a></td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        if($nume > $limit ){ 
        echo "<table align = 'center' width='50%'><tr><td  align='left' width='30%'>";

        if($back >=0) { 
        print "<a href='$page_name?start=$back'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>PREV</font></a>"; 
        } 

        echo "</td><td align=center width='30%'>";
        $i=0;
        $l=1;
        for($i=0;$i < $nume;$i=$i+$limit){
        if($i <> $eu){
        echo " <a href='$page_name?start=$i'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>$l</font></a> ";
        }
        else { echo "<font face='Verdana' size='4' color=red>$l</font>";}        
        $l=$l+1;
        }


        echo "</td><td  align='right' width='30%'>";

        if($this1 < $nume) { 
        print "<a href='$page_name?start=$next'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>NEXT</font></a>";} 
        echo "</td></tr></table>";

        } 
        ?>
```

The code below is edit.php. It's supposed to display the various fields when clicked to allow for editing but it isn't picking any field. What i'm i missing?

```
<?Php
require "config.php";   
$sql = "SELECT FROM receipt  WHERE ID=  :ID";

$stmt = $dbo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':ID', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);  
$stmt->execute();
?>

    <form action="update.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table align="center">
   <tr>
   <td> <label><strong>Full Names</strong></label></td>
     <td> <input type='text' name='name' value=" <?php echo $row['name']; ?>"  />
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?> " /> <br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

     <td><label><strong>ID/Passport No. </strong></label></td>
  <td> <input type="text" name="pass" value="<?php echo $row['id_passno']; ?> " /><br /></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> <label><strong>Phone No. </strong></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $row['phone_num']; ?>" /> <br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td> <label><strong>Amount (KShs.) </strong></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['Amount']; ?> "/> <br /></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
  <td> 
          <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="CANCEL" onClick="return confirm('Discard changes?');" />
      <br></td>


     <td> 
          <input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="SUBMIT" />
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: why two opening form tag.

Comment: That was an error while posting the question. Thanks for the observation

Comment: Is this part okay?         if(strlen($start) > 0 and !is_numeric($start)){

Comment: Yes, because it works with delete.